Visual Studio: The referenced component could not be found
I'm setting up a new laptop for my development work. I have fetched the latest code from the remote repo, and have no uncommitted changes.
Our .NET-based solution has a number of NuGet package references. When I first opened the solution I was told that the packages were missing from this computer, so I clicked the option to have them restored. They were then downloaded - I can see them in the solution's \packages folder.
However, when building the solution, one of the projects - and only one - tells me that the references (which come from those NuGet packages) cannot be found. Opening the References node, I can see that they all have yellow warning indicators.

I've compared the project file for the problem project with that of a 'good' project, and the <Reference /> elements are identical - the <HintPath /> values do point to the correct .dll in the solution's \packages folder.
Here is a screenshot from another project in the same solution - you can see that the same package references are recognised...

Both projects specify the same package references...

I've cleaned the solution, I've deleted-and-restored all packages, I've removed and re-added NuGet references...  I don't know what else to try.
Can anyone explain why these package references are not loading for this one project?

What is the type of  the only one project with the issue?

Is this project in the root directory of solution? Will the error disappear if you use absolute path in <HintPath>?

The project contains both WebForms and MVC (originally a WebForms project to which MVC was added). The project is inside the solution folder, as are all the other projects (all the projects are immediately inside the solution folder). The packages folder is also at this level - immediately inside the solution folder.

Could you please check project structure folder under your solution again and make sure this  .csproj file of WebForms and MVC project is in this path: "Your Solution/WebForms and MVC /.csproj file".
Not included in sub folders
For example:
Your Solution/other projects/.csproj file
Your Solution/Pacakges
Your Solution/WebFormsAndMVC project/Subfolder/.csproj file
Your Solution/Subfolder/WebFormsAndMVC project/.csproj file

There's only one project file (it was originally a WebForms project, then had MVC added to it), and it's located in solution-name\project-name\project.csproj.

Try to unload and reload the project to see if the issue persists. Besides, i found a similar ticket, please check if it helps.

I've reloaded the project, the solution, removed the project from the solution, restarted VS and added the project again...  None of this helps.

Please try to delete .vs folder and then reopen your solution to see if the issue persists.

I tried that many times. No change.

If you create a  new WebForms project and edit the project file to add package reference via <HintPath /> ,  will the issue disappear? It's would be better if you can share the entire .csproj file.
